# Can't see memory objects information on sessions managed by Hazelcast on Client-Server scenario

Tags: session, configuration, client-server, persistence, hazelcast

We have configured our application servers (two or three), to work as clients with a Hazelcast cluster (one or two members), for session persistence.
At first, we configured it as a two nodes of application servers with the embedded setup of Hazelcast, then we moved on to the client-server scenario.

On the embedded model, the console showed plenty of information related to the cache objects, replicating between nodes and moving from one instance to another when necessary.

On the Client-Server model we see both clients and members registered on the Hazelcast console, and we get basic information (versions, memory consumption, etc). But we cannot see session information (maps) travel and replicate.

We are pretty sure Hazelcast is working, because we have forced some intrincate combinations of client and member shutdowns that ensure that information recovered by next client must come from the surviving member, and data has traveled from cluster member to cluster member before going down to the client.

So, being convinced we are doing something wrong with the configuration, we humbly ask: Did anyone configure this before (sure, because it seems a very common configuration goal), and did you have similar problems? Did you solve them? How?

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to see cluster statistics on Management Center in client-server mode, if that's what you referred to as console?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Truth is with Tomcat members and clients show up, the Maps count grows, the number of hits runs up, the entries per node also grow... On the other side, With WebSphere Liberty Profile, the Maps number keeps a zero value, no matter what you do with your apps. We know that Hazelcast is working, clients and members appear listed at the Management Center, but no information is displayed about sessions.

Comment: I can even have Tomcat 8.5 and WLP 18.0.0.4 connected to a Hazelcast cluster, both keeping their information safe on the cluster, but no information from wlp maps show on the Management Center.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the statistics for caches to monitor them in the Management Center. Use the  element or setStatisticsEnabled() method in declarative or programmatic configuration, respectively, to enable the statistics of maps you want to see on Management Center.

Comment: ¿Do you mean to add this property:   <properties>
     <property name="hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled">true</property>
   </properties> to the hazelcast-client.xml? That I already did. This allows the Console to register/show the clients. But with WebSphere Liberty Profile, we still get no data on maps, hits, etc.

Comment: I meant under the map config:    <map name="default">
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>......

Comment: OK, I added the line to the map section on hazelcast.xml, the configuration file for the hazelcast cluster member process... Nothing obvious changes. hazelcast-client.xml has no such section at all (I checked the xsd file). Anyway the cluster member shows tomcat session information on the management console, while no informantion from the WLP can be found, so I think the hazelcast cluster config works well.

Comment: Are these maps or caches ? If you use `HazelcastInstance.getDistributedObjects()` you'll see what all exists and the type of each. Caches follow the cache specification and are not visible by default. If you have the Management Center the XML display per member panel shows what is in use, this might differ from the XML file if Java code has modified it after loading.